# How to maintain application state in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to maintain the state of an application .please tell me how to save the state of the application in windows phone 7?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read about life cycle of app, tombstone,dormant,active,closed.

You might need to use some state helpers to maintain controls state. Check link below

http://lnluis.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/managing-application-state-in-windows-phone-7/

This one is what i prefer but it depends on your app design.
http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/

Read this:
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Tombstoning_helper_for_Windows_Phone_7